# How to hide file path in URL?

Tags: php, url, filepath

What would be the best way to way to change my URL address to a custom one? Currently my website shows:

http://nkonecny.com/_pages/_portfolio/port.html

I want to change it to something like this:

```
http://nkonecny.com/portfolio
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrites.

[Here is a good linux/apache tutorial](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Answer (score 4):

.htaccess would be the best option.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite will do rewrites of this sort, but your pages have to follow a fairly strict naming/pathing convention for it to work. If you've got arbitrary path->names, then this won't work and you'll probably have to resort to a series of Apache 'Alias' directives.

Comment: Could you expand on this a little more? Because you are right, my whole website has hauppauge of different pages that have been added over the months.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use URL rewriting.  If you are using apache, you can get full information here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html