# how to hide embeded file URL that can watch in inspectElement by browser

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, security

I found this topic. 
[How to hide file path in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999720/how-to-hide-file-path-in-url)

But in that topic's case, that's a URL showing on addressbar

My Video file URL is inside that cannot found on address bar  but can found in ViewPageSource or InspectElement.
I want to hide the Video URL from Viewpagesource or InspectElement.

How can I do?  Do I need to use Signed URL service from Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0):

If you have mod_rewrite in your server, then you can do something like this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oranges.html$ apples.html
```

You can use regex, so you can make dynamic pages as well from a simple sintax.

Comment: I want to hide xx section in my video URL http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:1935/VodSecure/_definst_/mp4:vod1/1000/LOVELIVE_SH_ED_EP01_FREE_10TQ11122009DET06A.mp4/playlist.m3u8

Comment: you can't hide the ip/domain, that's how a browser knows where to look, plus it prevents hackers to do phishing attacks. In case you want to prevent from piracy, what you can do is to rate-limit per video + to add hotlink protection and to generate custom tokens for each video ( each will expire after a certain amount of time ). So, direct linking won't work.